# How to assign address to a pointer parameter

Tags: pointers, go

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a `struct` pointer and points it to another address.

I know I can simply write a function that takes a pointer and manipulates `struct` fields like so:

```
func ManipulateStruct(myPointer *MyStruct) {
    myPointer.Field1 = "new value"
    myPointer.Field2 = 10
}
```

However, is it possible to write something like:

```
func ManipulateStruct(myPointer *MyStruct) {
    newPointer := new(MyStruct)
    newPointer.Field1 = "new value"
    newPointer.Field2 = 10

    // myPointer = &newPointer <-- illegal
    // cannot use &newPointer (type **MyStruct) as type *MyStruct in assignment

    myPointer = newPointer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `new` makes a pointer to your `struct` so you need pointer like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/tH6dE4oujyM):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var ptr *MyStruct
    ManipulateStruct(&ptr)
    fmt.Println(ptr)
}
func ManipulateStruct(myPointer **MyStruct) {
    newPointer := new(MyStruct)
    newPointer.Field1 = "new value"
    newPointer.Field2 = 10
    *myPointer = newPointer
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
}
```

Output:

```
&{new value 10}
```

Comment: I see, so it needs to be a pointer to a pointer... Is it possible with just regular pointers, though?

Comment: What does it mean to do this? Returning `*MyStruct` and received by pointer is totally satisfied.

Comment: By "regular pointers", I was asking if it would be possible using just `*MyStruct` instead of `**MyStruct`. However, it seems that this is impossible, so this looks like the only possible answer. However, I will wait a little more for other answers before accepting this one.

Comment: It is better to avoid unnecessary pointers try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/uUJS9BIhsgD), I hope this gives you idea.

Comment: Also [this](https://play.golang.org/p/UQcGjDqVjHg) makes your code cleaner I think.